# Programmatically connecting to ZooKeeper ensemble

Tags: c++, .net, apache-zookeeper

I don't understand how I'm supposed to connect to a ZooKeeper ensemble as opposed to a standalone server.  From what I see the API expects a single connection string - to an individual server!  But what if this specific server is down, while the ensemble as a whole is still up and running?  Should I know all the nodes in advance and try them in sequence?

I am using ZK from both C++ and .NET applications, but I don't think it matters here conceptually.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One should read the [documentation](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/trunk/zookeeperProgrammers.html) more carefully :) The way to do it is to list all the servers as part of the connection string, as explained in the docs:

> To create a client session the application code must provide a
>   connection string containing a comma separated list of host:port
>   pairs, each corresponding to a ZooKeeper server (e.g. "127.0.0.1:4545"
>   or "127.0.0.1:3000,127.0.0.1:3001,127.0.0.1:3002"). The ZooKeeper
>   client library will pick an arbitrary server and try to connect to it.
>   If this connection fails, or if the client becomes disconnected from
>   the server for any reason, the client will automatically try the next
>   server in the list, until a connection is (re-)established.